# How to prepare and show a "find" or "search" dialog in word with vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to prepare a find dialog that finds all the highlighted text in a document.
I tried building this with the macro recorder, but it wouldn't display the dialog or find the text.

This is my code:

```
Sub searchForHighlights()

Dim match As Object
Set match = Application.Dialogs(wdDialogEditReplace)

match.Find.ClearFormatting
match.Find.Highlight = True
With match.Find
    .Text = ""
'    .Replacement.Text = ""  <<< I don't want my text to be replaced
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With

match.Show

End Sub
```

This part is evidently wrong:

```
Set match = Application.Dialogs(wdDialogEditReplace)
```

Answer (score 1):

I submitted part for searching highlighted text. But one thing... I don't quite understand what is functionality behind your "find dialog". Could you describe it more clearly?

Maybe you want to show your "find dialog" with all options set up?

```
Sub FindAllHighlighted()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Highlight = True 'searches for highlighted text
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = "" 'don't bother it wo'nt replace your text
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
Selection.Find.Execute
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I was really looking for was to open the find dialog (with the appropriate settings) which can be done with this:

Dialogs(wdDialogEditFind).Show

THanks anyways!

Comment: Glad you found your answer ;)